# how to implement Alphabet scroll in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there's any plugin or way to implement this kind of scrolling in flutter?

**To be specifi, the letters column on the right on the right, such as highlighting the current alphabet letter, or if a letter is tapped, the scrollview goes directly to that letter header.**

For sorting alphabetically, we can do that with `List.sort()`, for sticky header, we got some nice plugins as well.

[image: contacts list iamge]

Comment: You could use a `ListView` using an ordered `List<YourModel>`, then use `FlatButtons` on the right side of the screen. When pressed they scroll to the first index of said letter

Comment: You might have to implement it in the same manner that was initially implemented in Android libraries that provide this behavior.

Comment: @FlorentUguet this works, for now, I was looking for some sort of scroll through the letters, I think I will get back to it later. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this plugin sticky head
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sticky_headers

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return new StickyHeader(
        header: new Container(
          height: 50.0,
          color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
          padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: new Text('Header #$index',
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        content: new Container(
          child: new Image.network(imageForIndex(index), fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: double.infinity, height: 200.0),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This library sure does create sticky headers for list item. But can we group list items based on alphabets using this library as the question asker has mentioned?

Comment: Sorting would make this package golden.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

[AZlistview](https://pub.dev/packages/azlistview)