# How can I create a list with letters as headers?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I want to make a list of currencies in alphabetical order with letters as headers. Please have a look at the pictures for better understanding.

[This is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeGdI.png)

[The list I have been able to achieve so far (A simple one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G4Cg.png)

I searched for packages but I couldn't find anything as per my need. Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like: [how to implement Alphabet scroll in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817222/how-to-implement-alphabet-scroll-in-flutter?rq=1)

another options is: You can make a Map for example

```
countriesDict = {"a" : {"Algeria, Andorra", "b" : {"Bolivia, Bosnia ...."}}}
```

and retrieve it it in your code. For example:

```
for (country in countriesDict) {
  ... Your code to sort it out
}
```

and then display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to implement your desired result easily. 
[Grouped List](https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list)

Rest of it depends on your design.